# Total effective percentage of $2$ events that have an $80\%$ success rate each attempt

Tags: probability

What is the total percentage of two tries if there is an 80% success rate on each try?

Example:
We have an $80%$ chance of a positive pregnancy when implanting of $2$ embryos via [IVF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_vitro_fertilisation). We have $4$ embryos total for a total of $2$ tries. What is the percent that we will be pregnant given $2$ tries?

Put more simply, what are the odds that with $2$ tries we will have a pregnancy, and what are the odds that after $2$ tries we will NOT have a pregnancy?

Answer (score 0):

The chance of getting pregnant a the first attempt is $0.8$. The chance of getting not pregnant at the first attempt and getting pregnant at the second attempt is $0.2\cdot 0.8$

This two probabilities have to be add up.

And the probability that after 2 tries we will not have a pregnancy can be calculated by using the *converse probability*.